# Avoid nested in loops

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have an issue with in loops, while I'm trying to look for two same-value-pairs in an array and an object:

```
for (features in geodata.features) {
    if (geodata.features[features].geometry.type == 'Point') {
        .....
    } else if (geodata.features[features].geometry.type == 'LineString') {
        for (itema in networkElemente) { //Here is the part whrere it gets problematic
            for (itemb in networkElemente) {
                if (networkElemente[itema].uuid == geodata.features[features].properties.a.ne.uuid && networkElemente[itemb].uuid == geodata.features[features].properties.b.ne.uuid) {
                    console.log('klappt');
                    var intraOrtsVerbindung = L.polyline([[networkElemente[Number(itemb)].coords.lat,networkElemente[Number(itemb)].coords.lng],[networkElemente[Number(itema)].coords.lat,networkElemente[Number(itema)].coords.lng]], {   
                        weight: 5,
                        color: 'green',
                        opacity: 1,
                    }).addTo(map);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have the array `networkElemente` and I have `geodata.fea... .a` and `.b`. Now I want to  look, if `geodata...a` has one entry the same as `networkElemente` and ...`b` has also one entry like `networkElemente`. This works fine with these nested loops, which will execute the part unnecessarily often. I want to seperate the loops so that if `networkElemente.length` wouuld be 1000 that it does not log 'klappt' 1million time, but only 2k time. So just the same result, but not so often.

Thanks!

Comment: In JavaScript, you should be using `of` for the `for` loop rather than `in`

Comment: That doesn't solve the propblem.......

Comment: You're doing it backwards. How about less than 1K? https://pastebin.com/5nHZA0cV (edit: fixed code)

Comment: Improved version: https://pastebin.com/ZJ49LF2r

Comment: Well this was fast.... Thank you! Although it seemed easy for you, you was a great help. Thanks! Don't you  want to write an answer so I can accept it? Lol I can't even give xyour comment an upvote...

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow

You problem here, apart for using `for...in` when you probably want `for...of`, is combinatorics.

The easiest optimization is to never check the same pair twice. You can do this by using a regular `for...loop` and offset the index of the nested loop:

```js
var networkElemente = [];
while (networkElemente.length < 1000) {
    networkElemente.push(networkElemente.length + 1);
}
var count = 0;
for (var a = 0; a < networkElemente.length; a++) {
    var itema = networkElemente[a];
    for (var b = a + 1; b < networkElemente.length; b++) {
        var itemb = networkElemente[b];
        count++;
    }
}
console.log("Count: " + count);
```

As for your problem with logging too often, simplest solution is to simple hold a counting variable and log once after the loop is done.

Logging 2K times isn't good for performance anyway :-)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using nested loops, you could use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and take the `uuid` as accessor for the wanted data. Then check if both exists and make your poyline.

```
var networkElementeMap = new Map(networkElemente.map(o => [o.uuid, o])),
    elementA = networkElementeMap.get(geodata.features[features].properties.a.ne.uuid),
    elementB = networkElementeMap.get(geodata.features[features].properties.b.ne.uuid);

if (elementA  && elementB) {
    console.log('klappt');
    var intraOrtsVerbindung = L.polyline([
            [elementB.coords.lat, elementB.coords.lng],
            [elementA.coords.lat, elementA.coords.lng]
        ], {   
            weight: 5,
            color: 'green',
            opacity: 1,
        }).addTo(map);
}
```